# How can the $PV^{\gamma}$ equation be used here? If it can't be used then how do you solve this problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

A motor tyre has a pressure of $3$ atm at a temperature of $27^\circ C$ If the tyre suddenly bursts what is the resulting temperature?
First of all, I believe this is not a quasi-static process and by "suddenly" i dont think there is any equillibrium maintained. This question is given as a homework problem under the section of Applications of the First Law of Thermodynamics. There was a solution on some other website to a very similar problem but they use the $PV^{\gamma}=constant$ equation and also the equation for ideal gas. But I dont see how they are able to use it since this is not a quasi-static process.

Comment: Well, the question arises whether the process is quasistatic (i.e. reversible) or not? What do you think? Based on the formula you've given in the problem, what kind of process does it look to you? And, does that process necessarily have to be a quasistatic one?

Comment: based on the formula it is an adiabatic process, and to apply the equation which i meant i thought the process needs to be necessarily quasistatic.

Comment: Well, if the process is happening suddenly, then it's not quasistatic, is it? The reason is that, adiabatic processes can be irreversible as well, as a sudden 'bursting' of tires involves no heat exchange. This is an example of an irreversible adiabatic process.

Comment: I am not familiar with the concept of reversible and irreversible yet, but the way the above equation was derived in Zemansky, it was meant for a quasistatic process. So how can the equation apply for a irreversible sudden process?

Comment: See this for the difference between a reversible and a quasistatic process: [Quasistatic vs Reversible](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/328168/quasistatic-vs-reversible-processes). Also, read these sites to understand what I am talking about:[1.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasistatic_process) 
  [2.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/156055/meaning-of-reversibility-and-quasistatic-processes)

Comment: thank you, i finally did get what you mean and this problem should be assumed as a quasi-static irreversible adiabatic process.

Comment: Glad to Help! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my judgment, your assessment is correct.  The subsequent expansion of the air is going to be irreversible.  To a first approximation, the expansion takes place against constant atmospheric pressure, and the behavior is essentially the same as if the air were contained in an insulated cylinder with a massless piston.  Of course, that part that ends up outside the carcass will, after a while, come to equilibrium with the surrounding air.  But the air remaining inside the carcass of the tire will heat up much more slowly, and so, at least for the purposes of this problem, the expansion can be considered adiabatic (and, as indicated previously, against constant atmospheric pressure).

Comment: heat up? i got a lower temperature value on applying the $PV^{\gamma}=constant$ equation.

Comment: and are we assuming the gas to be ideal gas too?

Comment: First it cools down, but then it very slowly reheats after after heat is exchanges through the carcass with the outside air (the latter not part of the process we are looking at).  And, for air, assuming ideal gas behavior up to 3 atm is certainly a valid approximation.